# What does the sbt assembly documentation mean by "already part of the container?"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am running into the deduplicate error in sbt assembly trying to package my multiproject spark job. I looked in the sbt assembly documentation, and it says

> If you're trying to exclude JAR files that are already part of the container (like Spark), consider scoping the dependent library to "provided" configuration:

But what do they mean by "already part of the container?" I have copied the full link below.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the specific target node (a *container* like Spark) has already all the required jars and there is no need to include the same jars in the assembly.

This is the meaning of **provided** scope, i.e. a particular library is provided in the running environment and therefore don't include it in the final jar just make a reference to it.